# Shortcode is displaying the content on top of the page

Tags: custom-post-types, php, shortcode, html

My custom made shortcode is displaying the content on the most top of the page, even tho I include the shortcode after the header. Why is this happening? Weirdly enough, the content that is inside the `$out` variable is being displayed normally under the header, but all the other content is on top of the page or hiding under the header.

```
// Shortcode for Use Cases caption

add_shortcode('Use_Case', 'use_case_shortcode_query');
function use_case_shortcode_query($atts, $content){
    global $use_case_categories;
  extract(shortcode_atts(array( // a few default values
   'posts_per_page' => '11',
   'post_type' => 'use_cases',
        )
   , $atts));

  global $post;

  $posts = new WP_Query(array( // a few default values
   'posts_per_page' => '11',
   'post_type' => 'use_cases'
        ));
  $output = '';
$out = ''; ?>


<div class="tab-pane active" id="all">
    <?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'use_cases',
        'posts_per_page' -1,
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );
    $all_films = new WP_Query( $args );
    ?>

    <?php if ( $all_films->have_posts() ) : // make sure we have films to show before doing anything?>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table">
            <?php while ( $all_films->have_posts() ) : $all_films->the_post(); ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php the_post_thumbnail() ?></td>
                <td><h3><?php the_title() ?></h3</td>
                <td>
                    <p class="lead"><?php the_excerpt() ?></p>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Read more</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_query() ?>
        </table>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

</div><!-- all films tab pane -->


<?php foreach($use_case_categories as $use_case_category) { ?>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="<?php echo $use_case_category->slug ?>">
        <?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'use_cases',
            'posts_per_page' -1,
            'orderby' => 'title',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'use_cases',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $use_case_category->slug
                )
            )
        );
        $films = new WP_Query( $args );
        ?>

        <?php if ( $films->have_posts() ) : // make sure we have films to show before doing anything?>
        <table class="table">
            <?php while ( $films->have_posts() ) : $films->the_post(); ?>
            <tr>

                <td><h3><?php the_title() ?></h3</td>
                <td>
                    <p class="lead"><?php the_excerpt() ?></p>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Read more</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_query() ?>
        </table>
        <?php endif; ?>

    </div>
<?php }  ?>


<?php
    if ($posts->have_posts()):
            ?>
            <!-- BS tabs -->

            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
                <li class="active">
                    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#all">All</a>
                </li>
                <?php foreach($use_case_categories as $use_case_category) { ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#<?php return $use_case_category->slug ?>" data-toggle="tab"><?php return $use_case_category->name ?></a>
                    </li>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
            <?php
        while ($posts->have_posts()):
                    //echo var_dump($posts->the_post());
            $posts->the_post();
            /*$out .= '<div class="use_case_boxes">
                <h4>Name: <a href="'.get_permalink().'" title="' . get_the_title() . '">'.get_the_title() .'</a></h4>
                <p class="Film_desc">'.get_the_content().'</p>';
                // add here more...*/

                                $out .= '<a href='.get_post_meta($post->ID, "location", true).'><div class="vce-row vce-element--has-background vce-row--col-gap-30 use_case_finance vce-row-equal-height vce-row-columns--top vce-row-content--top" id="el-6cc8dbe6" data-vce-do-apply="all el-6cc8dbe6"><div class="vce-content-background-container"></div><div class="vce-row-content" data-vce-element-content="true"><div class="vce-col vce-col--md-100p vce-col--xs-1 vce-col--xs-last vce-col--xs-first vce-col--sm-last vce-col--sm-first vce-col--md-last vce-col--lg-last vce-col--xl-last vce-col--md-first vce-col--lg-first vce-col--xl-first" id="el-f4a5f49c" data-vce-do-apply="background el-f4a5f49c"><div class="vce-col-inner" data-vce-element-content="true" data-vce-do-apply="padding margin  border el-f4a5f49c"><div class="vce-row-container"><div class="vce-row vce-row--col-gap-30 vce-row-columns--top vce-row-content--top" id="el-356c02e5" data-vce-do-apply="all el-356c02e5"><div class="vce-row-content" data-vce-element-content="true"><div class="vce-col vce-col--md-100p vce-col--xs-1 vce-col--xs-last vce-col--xs-first vce-col--sm-last vce-col--sm-first vce-col--md-last vce-col--lg-last vce-col--xl-last vce-col--md-first vce-col--lg-first vce-col--xl-first" id="el-4c08b71e" data-vce-do-apply="background el-4c08b71e"><div class="vce-col-inner" data-vce-element-content="true" data-vce-do-apply="padding margin  border el-4c08b71e"><div class="vce-row-container"><div class="vce-row vce-row--col-gap-30 vce-row-columns--top vce-row-content--top" id="el-86253324" data-vce-do-apply="all el-86253324"><div class="vce-row-content" data-vce-element-content="true"><div class="vce-col vce-col--md-100p vce-col--xs-1 vce-col--xs-last vce-col--xs-first vce-col--sm-last vce-col--sm-first vce-col--md-last vce-col--lg-last vce-col--xl-last vce-col--md-first vce-col--lg-first vce-col--xl-first" id="el-a1c3851f" data-vce-do-apply="background el-a1c3851f"><div class="vce-col-inner" data-vce-element-content="true" data-vce-do-apply="padding margin  border el-a1c3851f"><div class="vce-google-fonts-heading vce-google-fonts-heading--align-center vce-google-fonts-heading--color-b-72-72-72--45--5C00FF--FF7200"><div class="vce-google-fonts-heading-wrapper"><div class="vce-google-fonts-heading--background vce" id="el-5c7b806f" data-vce-do-apply="border background  padding margin el-5c7b806f"><h2 class="vce-google-fonts-heading-inner" style="font-family: " open="" sans";="" font-weight:="" 400;"="">'.get_the_title().'</h2></div></div></div><div class="vce-single-image-container vce-single-image--align-center"><div class="vce vce-single-image-wrapper" id="el-9632dafd" data-vce-do-apply="all el-9632dafd"><figure><div class="vce-single-image-inner"><img class="vce-single-image" src="http://ai.crafts-world.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Second-home-page-design-Recovered_03.png" data-img-src="http://ai.crafts-world.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Second-home-page-design-Recovered_03.png" alt="" title="Second-home-page-design-Recovered_03"></div></figure></div></div><div class="vce-google-fonts-heading vce-google-fonts-heading--align-center vce-google-fonts-heading--color-empty--45--5C00FF--FF7200"><div class="vce-google-fonts-heading-wrapper"><div class="vce-google-fonts-heading--background vce" id="el-8f301bd3" data-vce-do-apply="border background  padding margin el-8f301bd3"><div class="vce-google-fonts-heading-inner" style="font-family: " open="" sans";="" font-weight:="" 300;"="">'.get_the_content().'</div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></a></a>';

            $out .='</div>';
    endwhile;
  else:
    return; // no posts found
endif;
  wp_reset_query();
  return html_entity_decode($out);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Shortcode Functions are executed as a filter before the content is echoed. Thus, the content you want to display instead of the shortcode has to be returned, not echoed.